# "where exactly did I write that made you think I meant...?"

Tags: phrase-request

I wrote a report/proposal and my co-worker reviewed it and commented on it. He thought I meant one thing but in fact I didn't. So I wanted to ask him to point out exactly where he got that impression from my report that I was suggesting the thing he thought I was suggesting

I guess this following sentence is not correct:

> "where exactly did I write in this report that made you think I meant...?"

Comment: where exactly did I write in this report **something** that made you think I meant...

Comment: Or, **what** exactly did I write in this report that...

Comment: @DanielRoseman - yours is better than mine.